# WebSocket Error: Incorrect HTTP response. Status code 400, Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-core-signalr

I tried to implement SignalR for ASP.NET Core as documented here: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/SignalR-AspNetCore-Integration

But I always get an error. Browser console output:

```
DEBUG: 
Starting connection using WebSockets transport
Information: Normalizing '/signalr-myChatHub' to 'http://localhost:62114/signalr-myChatHub'
SCRIPT12008: WebSocket Error: Incorrect HTTP response. Status code 400, Bad Request
```

I'm using the latest version of all packages 3.6.2 and 
Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR 3.6.2-preview6.

**Web.Host/Startup.cs**:

```
#elif FEATURE_SIGNALR_ASPNETCORE
    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<AbpCommonHub>("/signalr");
        routes.MapHub<MyChatHub>("/signalr-myChatHub"); // Prefix with '/signalr'
    });
#endif
```

Copy-pasted **MyChatHub.cs**:

```
public class MyChatHub : Hub, ITransientDependency
{
    public IAbpSession AbpSession { get; set; }

    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public MyChatHub()
    {
        AbpSession = NullAbpSession.Instance;
        Logger = NullLogger.Instance;
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("getMessage", string.Format("User {0}: {1}", AbpSession.UserId, message));
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        Logger.Debug("A client connected to MyChatHub: " + Context.ConnectionId);
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        Logger.Debug("A client disconnected from MyChatHub: " + Context.ConnectionId);
    }
}
```

More-or-less copy-pasted View:

```html
@using EMetall.Web.Startup

@section scripts
{
    <environment names="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/signalr-client/signalr.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.signalr-client.js"></script>
    </environment>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var chatHub = null;

            abp.signalr.startConnection('/signalr-myChatHub', function (connection) {
                chatHub = connection; // Save a reference to the hub

                connection.on('getMessage', function (message) { // Register for incoming messages
                    console.log('received message: ' + message);
                });
            }).then(function (connection) {
                console.log('Connected to myChatHub server!');
                abp.event.trigger('myChatHub.connected');
            });

            abp.event.on('myChatHub.connected', function() { // Register for connect event
                chatHub.invoke('sendMessage', "Hi everybody, I'm connected to the chat!"); // Send a message to the server
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Version 4.2 it works out of the box.

You just have to [download](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates) it and then create the chathup, register the route and call it in the view and it works. Great.

See for example for the chathup, route and view:
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/SignalR-AspNetCore-Integration

Answer (score 0):

You need to use compatible versions of:

- [Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR) (currently 3.6.2-preview6),
- [signalr.min.js](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/49357828d311e0fa85a5d37f3c4d120bbcb1737a/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc/wwwroot/lib/signalr-client/signalr.min.js) (currently 1.0.0-rc1-update1) from [@aspnet/signalr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aspnet/signalr), and
- [abp.signalr-client.js](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/048f15cd3549ccae0409d72c3c78ba03c326d796/src/Abp.Web.Resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.signalr-client.js) (currently 3.6.2) to be released on [abp-web-resources](https://www.npmjs.com/package/abp-web-resources).

Comment: I could try it once again with a fresh download and install of version 4.2 and now it works out of the box!! Absolutely great. Thank you very much.